# Multiple output cells with UDF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to print multiple output fields in cells in Excel using a user defined function.

```
Function CAL(dinero, impuesto)
Dim strText As String
Dim num As Double

num = dinero * 6.8
strText = "Mas impuesto"

Range("A2").Value = strText
Range("B2").Value = num

CAL = dinero + impuesto
CAL = Application.Round(CAL, 2)
End Function
```

Current result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: When you use a VBA user-defined function called from a worksheet cell, it can only return a value (or array of values).  It can't do anything else to the worksheet, such as write values to other cells, etc.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with a Macro.

With a Function, you could output an array. But the cells would be contiguous and could not be specifically within the function.

For example, with your formula in `A1`

```
Function CAL(dinero, impuesto)
Dim strText As String
Dim num As Double
Dim calc As Double
Dim v(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant

num = dinero * 6.8
strText = "Mas impuesto"

calc = dinero + impuesto
calc = Application.Round(calc, 2)

v(1, 1) = calc
v(1, 2) = ""
v(2, 1) = strText
v(2, 2) = num

CAL = v
End Function
```

[image]

If your version of Excel does not have dynamic arrays, you can enter the formula as an array across the four cells; or enter four formulas using `INDEX` to return each individual component.

Comment: Thanks a ton! it works for me and i can add more code with this function with arryas. I appreciate your help.